# SQL creating column for each distinct value

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, amazon-redshift

I have a table that looks like this:

```
 date | title | count
------+-------+-------
04/20 |  foo  |  420
04/20 |  bar  |  194
04/21 |  foo  |  23
04/21 |  bar  |  100
```

I want to get a result like this:

```
 date | foo | bar 
------+-----+-----
04/20 | 420 | 194 
04/21 | 23  | 100
```

How can I do this in Redshift SQL? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Comment: You shouldn't used protected words for field names (date and count)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think the simplest way to do it would be to use case when with group by like so:

```
SELECT "date",
       SUM(CASE WHEN title = 'foo' THEN "count" END) AS foo,
       SUM(CASE WHEN title = 'bar' THEN "count" END) AS bar
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY "date"
ORDER BY "date"
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm probably just going to dynamically generate the query using ERB, since I have a lot of columns.